# Change form of input in Material css

Tags: html, css, input, material-design

I like Material css design but I have a problem with the input. The input form not so common for user who use it for first time. So how to change form of input into just like Bootstrap input (a box). Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details, and some example code. If you don't want to share the site, use something like codepen.io to display the issue, or paste it here please.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I mean how to change/use a <input type="text" /> tag in Materialize css with the result as same as <input type ="text" /> in Bootstrap which results a textbox not a thick underline as Materialize does. I hope it makes the question clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just change it. But you may use textbox as type and class "browser-default" for select.